# getline() has memory leak, test with valgrind

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

Here's the skeleton of my code:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {   
  int  n, offset, offset1;
  int error = 0;
  char *buf = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  char load_var[] = "load";

  while(getline(&buf, &len, stdin) > 0) {
    char cmd[65] = "";
    while ((n = sscanf(buf,"%64s%n",cmd, &offset)) > 0) {
      if (!strcmp(cmd,load_var)) {
        char str[65] = "";
        char another_str[65] = "";
        int var_num;
        buf += offset;
        if ((var_num = sscanf(buf,"%64s%n%64s%n",str,&offset, another_str, &offset1)) > 0) {
          some_function(str);                    
        }

        buf += offset;
      }
    }
  }

  free(buf);

  return error;
}
```

Valgrind returns the messaged:

```
==15414== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==15414==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15414==    by 0x4EA5F54: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:66)
==15414==    by 0x401B3B: main (dev.c:177)
```

I don't know where I'm using `getline()` wrong so that the program has memory error.

Comment: Do not change `buf` as with `buf += offset;`.  Only change the memory it points to.

Comment: `buf += offset` - that will invoke undefined behavior on your subsequent `getline` invokes, and your final `free`. Frankly, I'm amazed this doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

This comment is the correct answer:

```
buf += offset
```

> that will invoke undefined behavior on your subsequent getline invokes, and your final free. Frankly, I'm amazed this doesn't crash. – WhozCraig

Valgrind should also report "invalid realloc" or similar *before* it reports the leak.

Comment: "Valgrind should also report "invalid realloc" or similar before it reports the leak.", could, ub is ub.

Comment: @Stargateur You are mistaken: there is nothing UB about executing this program *under Valgrind* -- it's *guaranteed* to catch this (and similar) bug.